# "Washroom", "restroom", "bathroom", "lavatory", "toilet" or "toilet room" 

Tags: word-choice

I've always been confused by the terms *washroom*, *restroom*, *bathroom*, *lavatory*, *toilet* and *toilet room*. My impression is that Canadians would rather say *washroom* while Americans would probably say *bathroom* or *Saint John's* in the same situation.

I guess the difference here is not only in different kinds of English, but also in whether one is referring to a room in their house or in some public place.

Which do you usually use? Please specify the difference if you use more than two from those six with different meanings, and also where you are from (i.e. what type of English you speak).

Comment: This site has brought me to dismiss all of them and use ["the gents"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/), ["john", or "jack"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/), just for the fun of it.

Comment: In our somewhat uncouth house in the North-East of England this room is generally referred to as the "bog".

Comment: Anyone interesting could also have a look over here... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khazi#Etymology

Comment: As an aside, I've always found it amusing that Canadians use the genteelism “washroom” to avoid the word “toilet” but then the word “toilet” is always there on the sign due the requirement for French translations.

Comment: @Nohat: Funny indeed. Incidentally, do you know the most traditional words for it in French? I think it is "cabinet", but I am not sure. The waiter in Paris didn't understand me when I last used that, so I had to fall back on "toilettes".

Comment: @nohat: Actually most washrooms in Canada don't have bilingual signs. Only in certain cities or in government buildings. And also common signage will use symbols, or the words "Men/Hommes", etc.

Comment: My favorite terms are "the little [boy's|girl's] room" and "the important place". (The latter from the campfire skit where the spies line up in a row and the head spy asks each of them in turn, "Do you have the important paper?" and when they can't answer in the affirmative, he shoots them; all the way until the last guy, who hands the boss a roll of toilet paper, and is thus reprieved. Naturally, if TP is the Important Paper, then the room where one uses it is the Important Place.)

Comment: @Cerberus: I would say that the word _cabinet_ is quite old-fashioned, my grand-mother use it, but that's all. Otherwise, there might have been problem with the pronunciation. As an aside, one could also say "aller aux water" in french, as an allusion to the W in WC.

Comment: Having family members in the US Navy means I sometime use *"the head"*.

Comment: @Marthaª I enjoy using The Simpsons' "the little magicians' room" (complete with actual little magicians and a bar). The phrase, I mean, not the room.

Comment: @BrianHooper too bad I'm uninteresting.  :D

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm American, and I've never heard the bathroom referred to as *St. John's*. It's colloquially referred to as *the john*, but not politely. Usually this room is referred to euphemistically, and there are degrees of social class associated with the terms. Here are a few, in order of most to least polite or high-class.

- The gentlemen's (or ladies') room
- The men's (or women's) room
- The restroom
- The washroom
- The bathroom
- The facility
- The toilet
- The john
- The jakes
- The crapper
- The shitter

Comment: Thanks Robusto for this input, but you only added more fuel to the fire. So far I would want to know only the differences between those terms that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: @brilliant: The arrangement in levels of politeness is the only operative distinction. That is a difference, and the main one, among all the words you list as well.

Comment: @Robusto: Aaaah! I see. Is this the case only in American English or it's this way in other types of English as well?

Comment: @Robusto: I heard "St. John's" from one American guy who is from Texas.

Comment: Don't forget 'the water closet.'

Comment: The head.  The little boys/little girls room.  The can.  Also, I've only ever heard "the facilities" and never just "the facility".

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard/seen "The gentlemen's room" or "The women's room". It's always "The men's room" vs. "The ladies' room".

Comment: Even in the US I've had people not know about restroom and want bathroom, or vice-versa. Seems to depends on the area.

Comment: @brilliant: If you only want to know about the terms listed in the question, I'll just say that even though I'd understand it, I doubt I've *ever* heard anyone refer to a *"toilet **room**"*.

Comment: I heard "little boys' (or girls') sandbox" a few times in my teen years.

Answer (score 23):

In the US we typically say "bathroom" for the room in our home that contains the toilet.

When in public and trying to be polite we ask directions to the "restroom". Indeed, most signs in restaurants, bars and airports will use the word "Restrooms" to direct people to the toilet.

My limited experience in the UK is that everyone is more literal and uses the word "Toilet". Many years ago in a museum in the UK I asked a guard for directions to the "restroom". He said "There's no place here for you to lay down, sir." I expect he was "taking the piss" which is an entirely different thing.

Comment: Exceptional piss-taking for the guard to have said “no place to lay down” to you, rather than the expected British English “nowhere to lie down”... ;-)

Comment: @Brian - that's a 15+ year old memory. And he may have actually said "no **room** where..." - he did __seem__ genuinely puzzled IIRC, but in hindsight, piss-taking he probably was.

Answer (score 23):

The room used for defecation is almost always referred to by euphemism.

### Bathroom

In Britain this still means a room containing a bath.

### Lavatory

This used to mean no more than a room used for washing. It was identical to washroom. "From Late Latin lavātōrium, from Latin lavāre to wash."

### Toilet

The word toilet is a euphemism. It previously was used to refer to the early morning routine of preparing for the day by washing, combing hair and applying various potions. So far as I know it did not include defecation and was therefore a perfectly innocuous and polite subject for general conversation. It can be startling to read the word when used in that sense in older books or artworks.

[image: Titian - A woman at her toilet] 
A woman at her toilet - Titian.

### W.C.

A euphemism in Britain (and some European countries) was water closet, nowadays abbreviated to W.C. Taken literally it implies no more than a small room provided with a supply of water - nothing offensive there.

[image: WC sign from UK signmaker]

### Popularity

The [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) provides these counts

```
toilet      1540
lavatory     546
WC           227
W.C.          13
```

### Progression

It seems that euphemisms must be constantly renewed by replacement as they become tainted by association with the taboo subject. This replacement proceeds at different rates in different countries, cultures or social groups. This means that, in time, new words must also be found for the existing meanings of words like convenience.

Comment: "A common euphemism in Britain is water closet..." is entirely false.

Comment: @e101: I have amended my reply pending some research.

Comment: "WC" is far5 more common on mainland Europe than Britain.

Comment: Notwithstanding [this version of "In the Quartermaster's Stores"](http://www.allthelyrics.com/forum/identify-it/73129-name-and-lyrics-for-dittie.html), when I was a boy scout (Southern UK) we always sang **My eyes are dim, I cannot see, I left my specs in the W.C.**

Comment: Water closet does not refer to a little room, but to the fact that water creates a seal between the foul gases in the drain pipes and the room. Details in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_closet

Comment: @Pablo. The article you link to says *"The term "water closet" ("WC") was an early term for an interior or exterior **room**"* Also see [definition of closet](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/closet) as *"a small room with a door"*.

Answer (score 13):

I'm English, and would probably use 'toilet' most of the time, and always in the context of a private home. Or I might use 'loo' which is more informal, but maybe outdated/whimsical. Actually, on reflection, I think there's a subtle and complex social class issue around these two. Not sure myself exactly how it works, but anyone using 'lavatory' is probably related to the royal family, or wishes they were. But then 'lav'is somehow at the other end of the scale.

'Bathroom' is never used and is often found funny when used by Americans. So is their discomfort when you use 'toilet' in the US.

I might use Ladies and Gents in the context of a public facility/bar/restaurant - signage will often use these terms, although perhaps more often written Gentlemen. Actually, thinking about it, I'd always use Gents in a pub, possibly there's a need to reinforce one's own gender identity!

I can't think I've ever *heard* WC, but I've seen it used on architects' drawings, probably  for reasons of space.

Comment: In terms of social and class issues I was regularly beaten by my parents, and god-parents to say loo, not toilet. Toilet is unbearably common, and good little boys should never use it, apparently. In a similar way, lavatory is even more plebeian than toilet.

Answer (score 7):

I'd just like to agree with 2revs. For my sins, I went to quite a posh private school, and saying *toilet* was a definite no-no. *Lavatory* was the standard word, but at school most people said *bog*. So I was happy when *loo* left its original 'U' niche, and became fairly classless. I've lived outside the UK for ten years, but I wasn't aware *loo* had become dated.

Comment: Of all international words in current usage, I believe that "toilet" is the one most widely considered non-U all over Europe, including England. A reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U_and_non-U_English . I heard things were different across the pond, though. // In Holland, the taboo on "toilet" is now even seeping through to the upper middle class. As soon as the lower classes will have stopped using it, the cycle will be complete, and the upper classes might start using it again. So silly.

Comment: @Cerberus - What made it even sillier was there was a quaint idea that the upper and working classes shared a preference for 'calling a spade a spade' and that only the middle class went in for euphemisms - such cross class solidarity! I've always wondered if the working class saw it in quite the same light. And of course 'lavatory' is just as much a euphemism as 'toilet'. It's simply Latin euphemism vs French euphemism. That Wikipedia article is excellent, by the way - I'm afraid that's the way I was brought up to speak.

Comment: @RandomIdeaEnglish: I think there is something in that: u. class and w. class do share some older, simpler phrasings that m. class has dropped. In addition, u. class tends to pick up occasional idioms and pronunciation from servants and peasants, mainly in the country, which often start as ironic or affectionate imitation; this is very clear in Dutch. But you're right that many euphemisms originate in u. class before they get discarded. I do think that m. class tries to be more catholic than the Pope and overdoes it on the euphemisms.

Comment: @RandomIdeaEnglish: Oh, about class solidarity: w. class might have it to some degree, but I suspect that many won't make a distinction between u. class and m. class. // I used to resist U-speak too when I wasn't allowed to say certain words. Now I try to justify it by looking at it as an aesthetic thing, just like clothing and furniture. It's not too bad as long as you don't think U people are better people. // What also interests me is to what degree such things are the same internationally.

Comment: @Cerberus - Hi, it was meant as a joke, perhaps I should have said inter-class solidarity. :). Although I still have an RP accent, I think most of that 'U' stuff was knocked out of me at college, as we were in a distinct minority. And I really went off it when then the 'Ya's' came along. 'Are you going to the Hamilton-Smythes do?' - 'Oh, ya. Rather'. Our neighbourhood was 'gentrified' and they used the street itself rather like a public school (BrE meaning) common room, 'Ya this' and 'ya that' at the tops of their voices. Does it matter that we're wandering off-topic, by the way?

Comment: @RandomIdeaEnglish: Oh, there was a topic... right. I think I took your solidarity half-seriously. Somehow I think there will always be some sort of U, just with different idioms. And there has always been "gentrification", and its opposite. Isn't it a cycle? I find it fascinating that some people quickly adapt to the speech of whomever they are talking to, while others never do. How could this be? My mother always imitates accents involuntarily, while I never do. Do you also adopt curses? That would be funny.

Comment: Fo for loo at school, short for foricas. - Then again, very posh school :)

Answer (score 7):

In the military, the navy, coast guard, and marines refer to the bathroom as *the head*, the reason being that in the olden days the bathroom was positioned at the bow of the ship.

The army and air force refer to the bathroom as *the latrine*.

Answer (score 6):

I'm English, and agree with Robusto that I've never heard the phrase St. John's.

Although I have heard the room in question being referred to euphemistically as "The bathroom", I believe this to be an Americanism. Unless the bath is actually in there, it's a toilet, or a "loo" in more polite society.

In my house the bath is in the same room as the toilet, so the room is referred to in our house as a bathroom, but one were caught short in a public place I would normally expect one to ask "where is the nearest toilet?" as opposed to "where is the nearest bathroom/washroom/restroom?", although I'm certain their meaning would be understood.

I don't hear many people refer to it as a lavatory any more, although maybe that's more a reflection on the company I keep. Certainly though some people refer to it as a "Lavvy", which is just a reduction of lavatory.

I certainly haven't heard anyone in the south of England refer to it as a washroom or restroom, and I personally would not refer to it as such. Again, perhaps this is an American thing?

Comment: Thank you Andy for this answer. I heard "St. John's" from one American guy who is from Texas.

Comment: "Restroom" is definitely American. Canadians prefer "washroom" or "bathroom" (the presence of a bath is not required).

Answer (score 4):

I'm Canadian and we *very* seldom use "restroom" in spoken language, although you'll sometimes find it on signs in restaurants and whatnot. The most common term round here is "washroom" — "bathroom" is sometimes used, but only really in a house where the room actually *would* have a bath. One might also say either "men's room" or "ladies' room" (very seldom gentleman's or women's), but that's generally in public places where there's actually a distinction, and even then it's fairly uncommon, used most often by people attempting to be more polite.

I've never heard the phrase "St. John" in my life, and when people say "the John" they're usually trying to be funny. As far as "loo" or "lavatory" goes, I've only heard those said in either an affected tone or a false British accent, at least in Canada.

Comment: I was in a restaurant in Florida once when my colleauge asked the waitress where the "washrooms" were.  She said "You must be Canadian."  Apparently in Florida but toilets are called "restrooms".  I think in both Canada and the U.S. a "bathroom" is found in a residence, not a public place.

Comment: @JoelBrown No, in the US bathroom and restroom are both commonly used to refer to public facilities with no bath.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the original word actually was as most of today's words are euphemisms or even, as bathroom, a euphemism to avoid a euphemism. I'm a New Zealander of British stock (parents still speak British and I lived there a while). It comes down to :

toilet - a euphemism based on a woman's morning ritual, then applied to the room and now to both the room and the bowl

lavatory - means wash room and is a euphemism

loo - from the French for l'eau (water) and is essentially a room with water, a euphemism.

WC or water closet - a room provided with a water source, then applied to the actual apparatus.

bathroom - a room with a bath in the whole world except North America where it now doesn't need a bath and is used as a euphemism so that Americans don't have to use another euphemism like toilet or lavatory.

restroom/washroom - variations on bathroom

heads - a boating term used for waterborne craft and naval land institutions, similar to galley (kitchen), brig (jail or cell), wardroom (dining room) etc.

latrines - simple toilet especially in the military, often temporary and little more than a hole with a board above it. Now often used by the Army as a general term.

Then you have the more vulgar, of varying vulgarity, terms such as dunny, bog, john, can, and even more vulgar cr*pper, sh*thouse etc. It appears that vulgarity begets accuracy.

Comment: As a southern Brit, I agree wholeheartedly that a **bathroom** would normally contain a bath, often also a toilet, & quite likely also a wash basin.  But, these days, a **bathroom** *may* contain a shower instead of a bath (together with toilet & washbasin).  At home, we have an "upstairs bathroom" containing a bath, toilet & wash basin; and a (larger) "downstairs bathroom" containing a walk-in shower, toilet & wash basin.  One could refer to a "**shower room**", but personally (& possibly for no good reason) I tend to think of a **shower room** as *not containing a toilet*.

Answer (score 3):

In Australia, it's almost universally called "the toilet", even amongst strangers (e.g. if asking someone the way to the nearest public toilets, you'd be inclined to ask "do you know where the toilet is?" or perhaps "do you know where the toilets are?").

Americanism is fairly pervasive here, though, so it's not entirely unheard of to say "I need to go to the bathroom", but it's definitely less common.

Australian English often co-opts a bastardisation of both British and American English with some local variation thrown in. For instance we use both "lift" and "elevator" to mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Canadian and we most commonly refer to it as the "washroom", which some of my American friends consider weird. When being informal, "bathroom" is the next most common non-slang term.

Answer (score 0):

Did I miss it,or has no one submitted "commode" as a genteelism?

Answer (score 0):

To look at this from a different aspect (and at the risk of duplicating some comments expressed previously), as a southern Brit, I would say:

- a **dining room** is where you dine;
- a **sitting room** is where you sit;
- a **bedroom** is a room with a bed;
- a **bathroom** is a room with a bath (or maybe a shower), and optionally also a toilet and/or washbasin;
- a **shower room** is a room with a shower, and maybe also a toilet and/or washbasin;
- a **toilet** (referring to a room) is a room with a toilet and maybe also a washbasin;
- a **washroom** is where you wash - either yourself, or the dirty dishes!;
- a **restroom** is where you rest, and should therefore contain comfortable chairs, recliners, a 'day bed', or similar furniture for resting in;

and so on.